# I'm using java on newbeans and I run the code but every time I try to write it doesn't write

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to enter the numbers but every time I do it, it doesn't response

here's my code

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Other/File.java to edit this template
 */
package com.mycompany.firstproject;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class Idc4den4m3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a numbuh, user");
        int f=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

it's not only in this code, but all of the codes that I previously worked on

Comment: What happens exactly when you try to run this code? How do you try to run it? Please tell and show any details that will help us to better understand your code, question and problem. The [ask] and [tour] links can help with this.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, well, I just used scanner codes and as you can see in the code above, and when I run it and try to write, it doesn't response at all :(